# Proper way to add my own Framework to new Target in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks

I have developed my own framework. In the same Xcode project I have a target which is an iOS executable (app) that uses the framework.

What is the proper way to add and embed my framework in the target?

The only thing I have been able to get to work is when I provide paths to the temp build directory, you can see my lib is linked to `build/Debug-iphoneos`:

[image: You can see my lib is linked to build]

And I have to include the temp build directory in my Framework search paths, e.g.:

```
/XCode_Build/TDTPhotoLib-hiiogugjwmaajpcurftmlyveoies/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos
```

This just doesn't seem right the right way to set it up.